# Mixin Enums and checking if an Enum object is one of a subset of the class

Tags: python, class, enums, class-method

I have a mixin `str` + `Enum`  class that allows other parts of my code to access the string representation of my variable states.

There's a specific Enum `citrus` type that can be from a subset of all the possible enumerations. Currently I'm using a `classmethod` to check "citrus-ness" as such:

```
from enum import Enum

class Fruits(str, Enum):
    apple = "apple"
    banana = "banana"
    orange = "orange"
    lemon = "lemon"

    citrus = {orange, lemon}

    @classmethod
    def is_citrus(cls, state):
        return state in cls.citrus
```

[Usage]:

```
>>> o = Fruits.orange
>>> Fruits.is_citrus(o)
True
```

My questions are:

- Is class method appropriate there?
- Is there a better way to improve how "citrus-ness" is checked?
- Currently, I'll have to use the `Fruits.is_citrus` methods to check `o` Enum object, how could the `Fruit` class be changed such that I can do something like `o.is_citrus()`?

Comment: Did you mean to write `class Fruits` instead of `def Fruits`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it a normal instance method:

```
class Fruits(str, Enum):
    apple = "apple"
    banana = "banana"
    orange = "orange"
    lemon = "lemon"

    citrus = {orange, lemon}

    def is_citrus(self):
        return self in self.citrus
```

I'm not positive the `citrus = {orange, lemon}` does exactly what you think it does (it ends up being a string representation of a set rather than an actual set) -- rather than having `citrus` be its own enum value I'd implement the concept of "citrus-ness" solely within `is_citrus`, like this:

```
    def is_citrus(self):
        return self in {Fruits.orange, Fruits.lemon}
```

Comment: Ugh this is why string enums defeat the whole point. It is understandable for backwards compatibility, but that's it's it

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about using a `@property`?

```
class Fruits(str, Enum):
    apple = "apple"
    banana = "banana"
    orange = "orange"
    lemon = "lemon"

    @property
    def is_citrus(self):
        return self in ['orange', 'lemon']
```

```
>>> o = Fruits.orange
>>> o.is_citrus
True

>>> a = Fruits.apple
>>> a.is_citrus
False
```